# C# GetResponseAsync with callback usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I'm kind of stuck with implementing a web api by using `HttpWebRequest` and it's *async/await* usage.

I need to send `GET` (or `POST`) requests and recieve a responses while not blocking the UI.

First implementation was through `BeginGetResponse` method where I could set a callback and parse the result.
But second implementation is needed to be done through *async/await* functionality and I really can't understand how it should work.

First implementation:

```
public class WebRequestGenerator : IRequestGenerator
{
    public IAsyncResult StartRequest(RequestData data) //data is my own class which aggregates some uri and callbacks' actions
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(data.uri);

        // here I create a callback which will parse response and call user's appropriate actions for success and exceptional cases.
        AsyncCallback completed = RequestCompletedCallback(data.successRequestAction, data.errorRequestAction);
        return request.BeginGetResponse(completed, request); //here I can set a callback
    }
}
```

For second implementation I should use

```
 return request.GetResponseAsync()
```

where I can't control the result. In this case I return `Task<WebResponse>` , but actually I want a possibility to return `Task<T>` where `T` is a class to which the response will be deserialized to.

Any help?